# What is the meaning of "?=>" in Scala 3?

Tags: scala, scala-3

I cannot find explanation of the following syntax rule:

```
FunType ::= FunTypeArgs (‘=>’ | ‘?=>’) Type
```

Answer (score 16):

`?=>` denotes a [context function](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/context-functions.html) type.

> Context functions are written using `?=>` as the “arrow” sign. They are applied to synthesized arguments, in the same way methods with context parameters are applied. For instance:
>
> ```
> given ec: ExecutionContext = ...
>
> def f(x: Int): ExecutionContext ?=> Int = ...
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> f(2)(using ec)   // explicit argument
> f(2)             // argument is inferred
> ```

So, if you think of `A => B` as being analogous to

```
def foo(a: A): B
```

Then you should think of `A ?=> B` as being analogous to

```
def foo(using a: A): B
```

It's just like a regular function except that the argument is taken as a context parameter. You can refuse to supply it (and it will be inferred from all of the givens in-scope, similar to `implicit` in Scala 2), or you can explicitly supply it using the `using` keyword.